# The meaning of tilde operator in model?

Tags: r

```
u=1:25 
plot(u~1)            
plot(u~0)
```

Why can't `plot(u~2)`produce a plot?  What is the difference between `plot(u~0)`and `plot(u~1)`?
Why do they have the same results?

```
y=1:25
x=sin(2:26)
plot(y~x)
plot(y,x)
```

and what is the difference between `plot(y~x)` and  `plot(y,x)` then?

```
x<-c(318,910,200,409,415,502,314,1210,1022,1225)
y<-c(524,1019,638,815,913,928,605,1516,1219,1624)
lm(y~x)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
395.567        0.896  

lm(y~x+1)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + 1)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
395.567        0.896
```

Why they have the same coefficients?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only `0` (without intercept) and `1` (with intercept) have meaning in `?formula`. So `u~2` will result in error.

Now `plot(u~0)` and `plot(u~1)` both plot `u` against running index, resulting in the same plot. See `?plot.formula`